# Movement of array along curve in BGE

Tags: game-engine, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am new with Game Engine, and I have a problem with something similar to bike chain. During simple animation, I used array modifier to duplicate those single chain elements, and then I used curve modifier, so that this chain was moving on a path created by me. Seems that all of those arragements don't work in Game Engine at all. Could anyone give me a hand with developing this on-curve-movement in Game Engine?Thank you very much for any help! With regards:)

Comment: Curves are not supported in the BGE. Therefore this can't work.

Comment: Is there any other way to develop the same movement? For example some kind of script in python? My project is simmilar to chain/conveyor belt, so I assume that this kind of animation in game is not so rare. Please give me a hand with that, I got really stuck :( Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you specifically need geometry to move, or would a moving texture suffice? If a moving texture is enough, I would advise you to look into the AnimAll plugin.

Comment: If you could use Follow path constraint, making your objects move along that curve, then you might bake action after it's ready to the keyframes and delete the curve.

Comment: I specifically need geometry to move, i need something (rigid body for example)to be moved on that conveyor belt, that is why texture is now enough.(